# Solr dataimport

Tags: mysql, solr, dataimporthandler

I struggle with importing datas from mysql to solr.
When I try to make a /dataimport, it gives me this response:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1
  },
  "initArgs": [
    "defaults",
    [
      "config",
      "data-config.xml"
    ]
  ],
  "command": "status",
  "status": "idle",
  "importResponse": "",
  "statusMessages": {
    "Total Requests made to DataSource": "1",
    "Total Rows Fetched": "50",
    "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
    "Full Dump Started": "2014-08-04 14:25:48",
    "": "Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.",
    "Committed": "2014-08-04 14:25:48",
    "Total Documents Processed": "0",
    "Total Documents Failed": "50",
    "Time taken": "0:0:0.87"
  },
  "WARNING": "This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future."
}
```

There is no error after running the command, but also it doesn't process any document.
I also checked the commit checkbox from the solr's interface, and tried to access the url with the "commit" parameter set to true, but without any luck.

My data-config.xml file looks something like this:

```xml
    <dataConfig>
    <dataSource 
            name="mysql"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" 
            user="root" 
            password=""/>

        <document name="id">

            <entity name="process" query="SELECT id, name, description, step_order, slug, is_private FROM Process WHERE `is_deleted`=false">
           <field column="id" name="id" />
                <field column="name" name="name" />
            <field column="description" name="description" />
            <field column="step_order" name="step_order" />
            <field column="slug" name="slug" />
            <field column="is_private" name="is_private"/>
            </entity>

        </document>

</dataConfig>
```

Also, my schema.xml fields section looks something like this:

```xml
<fields>

   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
   <field name="description" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
   <field name="step_order" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
   <field name="is_deleted" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
   <field name="is_private" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
   <field name="slug" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 

   <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_is" type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
   <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ls" type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_en"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_bs" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_fs" type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ds" type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- Type used to index the lat and lon components for the "location" FieldType -->
   <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" />

   <dynamicField name="*_dt"  type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_dts" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_p"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <!-- some trie-coded dynamic fields for faster range queries -->
   <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="*_pi"  type="pint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_c"   type="currency" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />

   <!-- uncomment the following to ignore any fields that don't already match an existing 
        field name or dynamic field, rather than reporting them as an error. 
        alternately, change the type="ignored" to some other type e.g. "text" if you want 
        unknown fields indexed and/or stored by default --> 
   <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" />

 </fields>


 <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. 
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
   -->
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Can you please take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi,
Check the logs while you are running your dataimport handler. 
There must be error why SOLR is unable to index the data.
Looks like there is a mismatch between your fields in database and fields in the index. Some data format mismatch.
Your logs will definitely show that

Comment: There is also a debug checkbox available in the user interface, or configurable by adding `debug=true` to the URL if you're requesting the handler directly. This should give you more debug information. If you haven't set up [SolrLogging](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging), you might not get the log messages you 're expecting.

Comment: Check the case of the `column` attributes in your data-config.xml. Usually solr uppercases the columns it fetches from the DB. So you should try `<field column="ID" name="id" />`.